# How to perserve array value after multiple async callback in node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, callback, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to execute multiple callback and at the same time storing value in array , but at the end array return empty.

Here is my code :

```
var sheetData = [];
async.forEachSeries(req.body.data, function (data, cb) {
    sheet.find({accountid: req.body.id}, function (err, doc) {
        if (doc == '') {// get the next worksheet and save it 
            var sheet = new sheet({
                accountid: req.body.id, 
                sheetid: data.sheetid
            });

            var jsonData = {};
            jsonData.sheetid = data.sheetid;

            sheet.save(function (err, doc) {
                if (!err) {
                    sheetData.push(jsonData); // trying to push in array , success
                    console.log("-----sheet data---- : ", sheetData);// data available here
                }
            });
        }
    });
    cb();
}, function () {
    console.log("-----sheet data---- : ", sheetData);// empty array 
});
```

Where I am doing wrong? Can anyone suggest me ?
Or, If any other alternative in nodejs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The callback is being called early. Try following:

```
var sheetData = [];
async.forEachSeries(req.body.data, function (data, cb) {
    sheet.find({accountid: req.body.id}, function (err, doc) {
        if (!doc) {
            return cb (); //sheet exists, call back early
        }

        // get the next worksheet and save it 
        var sheet = new sheet({
            accountid: req.body.id, 
            sheetid: data.sheetid
        });

        var jsonData = {};
        jsonData.sheetid = data.sheetid;

        sheet.save(function (err, doc) {
            if (!err) {
                sheetData.push(jsonData); // trying to push in array , success
                console.log("-----sheet data---- : ", sheetData);// data available here
                cb (); // all done, now we can call back
            }
        });
    });
}, function () {
    console.log("-----sheet data---- : ", sheetData);// lots of sheets
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, again not getting all sheetData at the end. its empty.

Comment: when I changed this (doc !== '') to (doc !='') its working fine., 
Thanks @Chris Satchell